# Why didn’t the sages sense a problem with "in God's image"?

Tags: theology, parashat-bereishit, adam

The Talmud ([Megillah.9b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.1.26?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Megillah.9b.1&lang2=bi) and [Tractate_Sefer_Torah.1.9)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.1.26?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Tractate_Sefer_Torah.1.9&lang2=bi) lists the 13 places/verses that felt problematic in the translation into Greek.

> "י״ג דברים שינו בה:
>
> 1. אלהים ברא בראשית.
> 2. אעשה אדם בצלם ודמות
> 3. ויכל בששי וישבות בשביעי..." and more

In #2 they changed the plural into the single but didn't change "image and likeness", indicating, probably, that they didn't see a problem with God having an image or form.

Why?

Comment: Maybe they thought about Book of Daniel on how G-d is described.

Comment: #2 doesn't say בצלמו ודמותו but צלם ודמות. Why do assume it's still God's צלם ודמות intended here?

Comment: This would mean that He created Adam as a physical being to exist in the world. This does not say that Hashem had a physical being so it does not need to be changed.

Comment: The Greek creation narrative is very close to the Jewish one. "Prometheus created man out of earth, and the goddess Athena breathed life into his creation."

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/773/sources-for-hashem-being-corporeal-incorporeal/94511#94511

Comment: @Alex Could you please post it as an answer, it might be very helpful.

Comment: @magicker72 Because it continues: " בְּצֶלֶם אֱלֹהִים בָּרָא אֹתוֹ "

Comment: I would say maybe they translated it as per Rashi, "let [Me] make man in the image and likeness of Mine [in my plans for people]". Not the Image Hashem has, but the image He owns. But, they apparently left "Yad Hashem", "charon Apo", etc... alone as well. More likely, they weren't worried about the Ptolemies understanding the anthropomorphic idiom. But these examples aren't common enough to be idiomatic.

Comment: A number of people posted answers quoting rishonim. Unqelus is far closer in time and culture to Hellene Egypt, and the Targum avoids anthropomorphism consistently. Even "prayed before Hashem" rather than *to* Him"

Comment: @AlBerko  בצלם אלהים ברא אתו can be understood as 'Elohim created him in an image' so leaving it in the Torah does not prove that the translators thought that it is permissible to presume Elohim has a body.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that Chazal understood "image and likeness" as the  Nefesh Hachaim does.

The [Nefesh Hachaim 1 (1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Nefesh_HaChayim%2C_Gate_I.1.3-4?lang=en) says:

> The use of the words *tzellem* and *d’moot* are not per their simple
> meanings, for it is explicitly written (Yeshayahu 40:18): “And what
> likeness will you compare unto Him.” Rather, their meanings imply a
> similarity in some feature, as in (Tehillim 102:7): “I am like a
> desert pelican.” It’s not that he was given wings and a beak, and not
> that his physical appearance was transformed into a pelican, but
> rather that he is described in that instance by his actions, that he
> wandered from place to place like the pelican in the desert (a lone
> bird that flies from place to place). This is per the early plain-text
> commentators (OBM).
>
> And so this is what is meant by *tzellem*: that the one resembles the
> other in some fashion.

Learn more in the Nefesh Hachaim to understand the non-physical resemblance.

Comment: Absolutely the same reasoning can be applied to all other changes. The sages feared that the text *could be* misinterpreted for example "נעשה אדם". It does not mean that there's no other metaphorical explanation or interpretation. It appears that you missed the point of the question.